# Late 2016 MacBook Pro 15' Kernel Panic

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

I purchased a new MBP 15 on Sunday, and today I had my first Kernel Panic while running Sierra 10.12.1 and was hoping someone could tell me what it says.

```
Anonymous UUID:       399FCD7A-F0CA-1ADD-4E3B-AEAE8BC3648D

Wed Nov 23 08:19:28 2016

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 0): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock:     0xffffff801b088f88, spinlock owner: 0xffffff8040208498, current_thread:     0xffffff8040208498, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x0
RAX: 0xffffff7f9cf525ec, RBX: 0xffffff81ba266000, RCX:     0xffffff9209bda000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff81da22ee20, RBP: 0xffffff81da22ee30, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff81ba266000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000003, R10: 0xffffff801b008e40, R11: 0x0000000080010000
R12: 0x0000000000000001, R13: 0xffffff920924b880, R14: 0xffffff81b9def700, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000000006, RIP: 0xffffff7f9cf525f5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81da22ecc0 : 0xffffff801aa05991 
0xffffff81da22ed20 : 0xffffff801a8a5a6f 
0xffffff81da22ee30 : 0xffffff7f9cfff4bc 
0xffffff81da22ee50 : 0xffffff7f9d00ea3b 
0xffffff81da22ee90 : 0xffffff7f9cff313d 
0xffffff81da22eeb0 : 0xffffff801aec2431 
0xffffff81da22eef0 : 0xffffff7f9b14fe5d 
0xffffff81da22ef40 : 0xffffff7f9d70c12e 
0xffffff81da22ef50 : 0xffffff7f9d714417 
0xffffff81da22ef70 : 0xffffff801aa059ae 
0xffffff81da22efd0 : 0xffffff801a8a5909 
0xffffff920924b9f0 : 0xffffff801a9ed01e 
0xffffff920924baf0 : 0xffffff801a9edfca 
0xffffff920924bb60 : 0xffffff801a97b0b8 
0xffffff920924bca0 : 0xffffff801a97a9bc 
0xffffff920924bcd0 : 0xffffff801a976523 
0xffffff920924bd00 : 0xffffff801ae582f0 
0xffffff920924bd20 : 0xffffff801aeecf1d 
0xffffff920924bd80 : 0xffffff801a9c7840 
0xffffff920924bdd0 : 0xffffff801a8f843c 
0xffffff920924be30 : 0xffffff801a8d5f61 
0xffffff920924be80 : 0xffffff801a8e9957 
0xffffff920924bf10 : 0xffffff801a9f26ae 
0xffffff920924bfb0 : 0xffffff801a8a5f66 
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[A55C1363-A09F-3755-9BD3-526A7A2C3B5B]@0xffffff7f9b132000->0xffffff7f9b165fff
     com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(5.0)[249D7BA8-3FD5-3207-A482-0605CB898037]@0xffffff7f9d705000->0xffffff7f9d764fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f9b546000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[A55C1363-A09F-3755-9BD3-526A7A2C3B5B]@0xffffff7f9b132000
     com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer(10.2)[550D81C2-81C1-39A3-8BC0-84B69A6AC215]@0xffffff7f9cfc7000->0xffffff7f9d17cfff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[A55C1363-A09F-3755-9BD3-526A7A2C3B5B]@0xffffff7f9b132000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f9b546000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.15)[51C08EBC-F91D-34E3-90CC-8F3D3011F8B2]@0xffffff7f9cf1b000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(31)[B14DC3D3-7250-3DA3-BF50-C666EBEDAF4C]@0xffffff7f9bd36000
        dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.74)[BC16864D-447E-3F3C-BA1A-280868E043BB]@0xffffff7f9cfbb000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[D01B501C-E5B8-36AC-930C-978C205EFEFF]@0xffffff7f9b212000
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.15)[51C08EBC-F91D-34E3-90CC-8F3D3011F8B2]@0xffffff7f9cf1b000->0xffffff7f9cfabfff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[A55C1363-A09F-3755-9BD3-526A7A2C3B5B]@0xffffff7f9b132000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[D01B501C-E5B8-36AC-930C-978C205EFEFF]@0xffffff7f9b212000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.ifdrea

Mac OS version:
16B2659

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Wed Oct 19 20:31:56 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.4~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 75CA1C4D-7BF4-321B-B544-D8F1B6D60EF8
Kernel slide:     0x000000001a600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801a800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801a700000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 887200999389
last loaded kext at 8503027184: com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    127 (addr 0xffffff7f9ce4c000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.displaylink.driver.DisplayLinkDriver    2.6.0 (75598)
zoom.us.ZoomAudioDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    127
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 103
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   278.23
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.23
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.74
com.apple.kext.AMD9500Controller    1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    540
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 103
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1110.4.1a8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   5.0.1f7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.23
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.15
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.74
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.6
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.74
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.0.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.20.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff801a9eae1f): "Spinlock acquisition timed      out: lock=0xffffff801b088f88, lock owner thread=0xffffff8040208498, current_thread: 0xffffff803f04b980, lock owner active on CPU 0x0, current owner: 0xffffff8040208498"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.21.4/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:418
Backtrace (CPU 5), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff920918baa0 : 0xffffff801a8f368c 
0xffffff920918bb20 : 0xffffff801a9eae1f 
0xffffff920918bcb0 : 0xffffff801a975487 
0xffffff920918bd80 : 0xffffff801a8fe0c9 
0xffffff920918bdc0 : 0xffffff801ade55f7 
0xffffff920918be10 : 0xffffff801adcba7a 
0xffffff920918be30 : 0xffffff801ad52f30 
0xffffff920918bea0 : 0xffffff801ad52bc5 
0xffffff920918bf10 : 0xffffff801ad5704a 
0xffffff920918bf50 : 0xffffff801ae27cba 
0xffffff920918bfb0 : 0xffffff801a8a5f46 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: mDNSResponder
Model: MacBookPro13,3, BootROM MBP133.0226.B00, 4 processors, Intel    Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.38f5
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics530Item, Intel HD Graphics 530, Built-In
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro450Item, AMD Radeon Pro 450, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE,   0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE,  0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x15A),     Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.47.1a8)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Belkin USB-C LAN, Ethernet, en7
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Yubico Yubikey II
USB Device: iBridge
USB Device: Belkin USB-C LAN
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 11.9
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 11.9
```

Comment: First thing to always check is whether all 3rd party kexts are up to date -     com.displaylink.driver.DisplayLinkDriver &
    zoom.us.ZoomAudioDevice 1.2

Comment: What were you doing when you had this kernel panic?