# Do All of the Macbook Pros Have That GPU-Kernel Panic Issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

Recently I upgraded my mid-2010 MacBook Pro from Snow Leopard to Yosemite. Everything seemed to be working just fine, and then, a few hours later, the kernel panics started.

Thankfully, I was able to find the solution here:

[Question about GPU Panic on Mid 2010 MacBookPro6,2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179825/question-about-gpu-panic-on-mid-2010-macbookpro6-2/304525#304525)

Now I am thinking about upgrading that MacBook Pro to a newer model, but I just saw somebody on here talking about having a similar issue with their 2016 MacBook Pro, hence my question.

So newer MacBook Pros have the same problem?

Comment: WHere did you see "somebody on here talking about having a similar issue with their 2016 MacBook Pro"?

Comment: Here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262118/late-2016-macbook-pro-15-kernel-panic

Comment: How is that related to GPU? as I cannot seen enough info in that question

Comment: It looks like that question was asked a year ago, and the author never got back for clarification of the issue he was having, so I guess it isn't clear whether or not this was an issue with the GPU. Of course, I just saw there was an issue with a 2016 MacBook Pro that had a kernel panic as I was looking around here.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there have been no widespread reports of kernel panics due to GPU related issues on 2017 MacBook Pro 15", and I doubt there are any. There's always some quantity that have hardware issues, but nothing outside of the norm. [According to Apple, the issues with the 2016 version were software related and patched in 10.12.2.](https://9to5mac.com/2016/12/07/apple-believes-2016-macbook-pro-graphics-issues-are-addressed-in-macos-10-12-2-update-according-to-craig-federighi-email/)

With that said, the norm doesn't seem to have a brilliant track record; for whatever reason, GPU failure seems to be medicore across their products. Here's a short list that I know of:

- [All 2011 MacBook Pros](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)
- [Mid 2012 and Early 2013 15" MacBook Pros](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)
- [2011 27" iMac](https://9to5mac.com/2013/08/16/apple-opens-graphics-card-replacement-program-for-some-mid-2011-imacs/)
- [Late 2013 Mac Pro](https://www.macrumors.com/2016/02/06/late-2013-mac-pro-video-issues-repair-program/)

That said, if any widespread issues are present, they probably won't begin to show up in wide numbers until some time this year. Widespread reports of GPU failure in the 2011 MacBook Pro didn't really garner support until [2013](https://www.change.org/p/timothy-d-cook-replace-or-fix-all-2011-macbook-pro-with-graphics-failure) with Apple doing nothing centralized until [2015.](https://www.macrumors.com/2015/02/19/2011-macbook-pro-repair-program-apple/)

Though, Apple (generally) is known for good support, and I wouldn't worry too much about this.